# C#, Nullable decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my database, v1 field is nullable field. but I define 0 (default) if the value is null.

```
public decimal? v1 {
  get {
    return this._v1; 
  }
  set {
    this._v1 = value ?? 0M;
  }
}
```

so now, the v1 is not nullable variable anymore.

but I can not do this,

```
decimal v2 = v1;
```

**The error message say, Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'.**

In this case, Do I have to convert to decimal, like this?

```
decimal v2 = Convert.ToDecimal(v1);
```

It very annoying job. and codes are look dirty too.

Anyone know better solution? please advice me.

Comment: Your original solution is dirty, what does it matter, if the new solution is dirty.  What is the point of having a nullable field if you assign it what already by default is the default value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No you don't have to convert the `decimal?`, you have access to the underlying value from the `Nullable` type e.g.

```
decimal v2 = v1.Value;
```

Assigning a default value to a `Nullable` type does not make it non-nullable, it just means it has a value. Nullable types have a `HasValue` property which helps you determine this.

Just for the record, I wouldn't recommend defaulting the value to `0` it would probably make more sense letting it default to `null` considering it *can* indeed be null. If you need to have a default value in your app you will probably want to use the `GetValueOrDefault` method e.g.

```
decimal v2 = v1.GetValueOrDefault(0m);
```

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to convert a `decimal?` to `decimal` but have the value to be `0` when `null`, you can do:

```
decimal? a = null;
decimal b = a.GetValueOrDefault(0m); // will contain 0 when null, otherwise the value
```

Read up on [GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You could also call `GetValueOrDefault` with no arguments, which will yield `default(T)`, which in the case of Decimal is 0, but I like to be explicit.

Answer (score 6):

I'm curious why you would define your app code variable as nullable but then set it to 0 if it's null. Is it just to avoid the exception if passing a null value from the database to your app variable? If your application doesn't absolutely need the nullable decimal variable, just check it for a DbNull as you're reading it out:

```
decimal myAppVal = rdr["DbColumn"] == DBNull.Value 
   ? default(decimal) 
   : (decimal) rdr["DbColumn"];
```

or explicitly set 0.0M instead of using default(decimal)

Design-wise, if you're finding yourself doing this often, then i'd suggest creating a generic extension method to read values out of the database. This way you can ensure that invalid casts are avoided and exceptions are handled, but more importantly that default values are returned in case of nulls. ;)

Something like (and I'm just spitballing here):

```
public static T CastFromDbTo<T>(object readerObject)
{
    T returnVal = default(T);
    if (readerObject is T)
    {
        var myValue = (T) readerObject;
        returnVal = readerObject != DbNull.Value && myValue != null
                ? (T) readerObject 
                : default(T);
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

Then you could grab your value like this:

```
var myAppValue = HelperClass.CastFromDbTo<decimal>(rdr["DbColumn"]);
```

or actually make an extension:

```
public static T CastFromDbTo<T>(this object readerObject)
{
    T returnVal = default(T);
    if (readerObject is T)
    {
        var myValue = (T) readerObject;
        returnVal = readerObject != DbNull.Value && myValue != null
                ? (T) readerObject 
                : default(T);
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

then you could just do this:

```
var myAppVal = rdr["DbColumn"].CastFromDbTo<decimal>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Value you assigned to v1 is `decimal`, but the type is still `decimal?`. That's why you can't assing it.

Try

```
decimal v2 = v1.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nullable Types have the properties `Value` and `HasValue`.

> **HasValue** - Gets a value indicating whether the current Nullable object has a value.
>
> **Value** - If HasValue is true, this contains the value if not its null.

```
decimal v2;

if (v1.HasValue) // check for null
{
  v2 = v1.Value;
}
```

Check out [MSDN - Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)